# angularJS: fetching client time from date time variable returns UTC time.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

fellas!

Using `Angular ui bootstŕap`, I'm making a timepicker for users. Users can set time (in 24 hour format). And I'm trying to get that value in controller.

So, when a user sets 13:00 as time, I need to fetch 13:00:00 but, what I'm getting is 2016-08-12T07:30:02.732Z

How can I obtain user entered value instead of UTC time.

```
<div ng-controller="TimepickerDemoCtrl">

  <div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" second-step="30" show-seconds="false" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="false"></div>

  <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime }}</pre>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
</div>
```

I have made a plunk which will give you a better idea. here's the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8HGeOFHLgeYEPTtaGKU?p=preview)

Comment: y dont you try to convert it in to your local time from utc.....i searched and unable to find a correct solution thats y i am saying like this

Comment: there is an angular build in filter called [date (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

If you want to only change the display you can use it like `{{mytime | date:"medium" }}` . 

Aside from that i think javascript uses the System locales for date and time so check those too as well to meet your country's locales